# Starting Wildfly to run in the background on AIX

Tags: bash, wildfly, aix, wildfly-10

I've a script to start WildFly to run in the background, but a strange thing is happening. If I start it from one shell and, afterwards, I restart it from another shell, my deployed apps stop working with the following error:

> WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" =>
>   "EpmsControlCenter-v2.ear")]) - failure description: "WFLYSRV0137: No
>   deployment content with hash 53ffc3840fcb342cff8400c8525045f7cf04b186
>   is available in the deployment content repository for deployment
>   'EpmsControlCenter-v2.ear'. This is a fatal boot error. To correct the
>   problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the
>   CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the
>   configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuration
>   file and restart."

Here is my startup script:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"

JBOSS_HOME="$DIR"
JBOSS_BASE_DIR="$DIR/nodes/$1"
JBOSS_PIDFILE="$JBOSS_BASE_DIR/log/pidfile"
LOG_FILE=$JBOSS_BASE_DIR/log/jboss-console.log
LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_MODULEPATH=$JBOSS_BASE_DIR/modules:$JBOSS_HOME/modules JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=$JBOSS_BASE_DIR -Djboss.node.name=node-$1 > $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
```

How can I improve it so this behavior goes away?

### EDIT #1

I've noticed that, besides the server's process, one more process is showing up:

> admin 15925342        1   0 08:13:59 pts/13  0:00 /bin/sh
>   /opt/server/oltp/bin/standalone.sh
>   -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/server/oltp/nodes/n2 -Djboss.node.name=node-n2

And this is probably the culprit.

**EDIT #2**

I've changed the script and the issue is no longer happening. Looking at both versions, can someone explain me what was causing the issue?

DIR="${0%/*}"

```
JBOSS_HOME="$DIR"
JBOSS_BASE_DIR="$DIR/nodes/$1"
LOG_FILE=$JBOSS_BASE_DIR/log/jboss-console.log
export LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
export JBOSS_MODULEPATH=$JBOSS_BASE_DIR/modules:$JBOSS_HOME/modules
export JBOSS_PIDFILE="$JBOSS_BASE_DIR/log/pidfile"

nohup $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=$JBOSS_BASE_DIR -Djboss.node.name=node-$1 > $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Why so complex a `DIR=` line in your script? Wouldn't `DIR="${0%/*}"` suffice? Also, have you tried following the instructions in the "To correct the problem" text you posted? Lastly, might there be a WildFly online community, mailing list or forum that would be able to provide more direct support for this product? It seems like your problem is with running or configuring the application, not with programming.

Comment: @ghoti, thanks for your help. This is script for AIX, not for Linux, many commands differ, but I'll try your suggestion. I can always redeploy the application, that is not the point, I need to know how I can restart without having to do so. This forum has thousands of questions about bash/batch, it's not all about programming, I think I can get the help I need a lot faster here.

Comment: I don't think I mentioned Linux anywhere in my comment. Perhaps you're thinking of someone else's comment. IIRC, AIX's default shell is actually `ksh`. Check [`man sh`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/sh.htm) and you may find that you have a POSIX compliant shell at your disposal, in which case it should support parameter expansion as I suggested.

Comment: As for your shell script, I see nothing syntactically incorrect in it, though for safety you might want to quote your variables and provide a little input validation on `$1`. I suspect your issue is not with the code of this script, but with elements of your environment which are not included in this question. As such, your question would be off-topic for StackOverflow, and perhaps better placed at http://unix.stackexchange.net or another forum with a greater focus on the toolset you're using.

Comment: Which version of WildFly ? Are you using the same user account to launch those scripts ? It seems to me that the deployment content is either not readable or deleted on the second start.

Comment: @ehsavoie, I'm using WildFly 10.1.0 and the commands are being executed with the same account, just separate shells.

Comment: Your deployment content has been deleted or is not accessible, that's the root cause of your error. Now the question is why ? Could you paste your logs ? Also where is your server installed and configured ? Could you have 2 instances running at the same time sharing maybe some folders ?

Comment: @ehsavoie, I don't think that's the problem, because it's reproducible. I just need to start it from one shell and restart it from another. It always behaves the same. The log doesn't show much more info than the one I've included in my post, it just complains about the failed operation and stops.

Comment: I would like the log before restarting: i'm almost sure you could 'see' the content deletion in there.

Comment: @ehsavoie, I've looked at the log and couldn't find any evidence of content being deleted. On the other hand, I noticed that after the stop the PID file is not deleted and, although the log prints normal stop procedure (including the final "...stopped in xxxxms"), the process remains alive.